# Help creating multi page web form with perl CGI

Tags: perl, webforms, cgi

I want to create a multi page web form using perl CGI that changes page based on a drop down selection. I have looked at tutorials for a multi page CGI form that only moves in order but I would like mine to be able to go to a different page based on the selection. I'm not sure how I should try to organize my different pages and handle switching pages without getting messy. Any suggestions to how to organize and move throughout the pages would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of the CGI script, the which UI element is the source of the submission does not make any difference at all. That matters are the name/value pairs your script receives.

If you want the form to be submitted without the user having to click a submit button, you'll need to look at JavaScript as that is a client side issue, not a server one.

Comment: I am looking to have one page where they pick a value from a drop down then click a next butter where it then picks a page to load based on the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [`Catalyst`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro#NAME)? An MVC architecture will control the code--if you know how to use it.

Comment: Perhaps going straight to [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) may not be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Dropdown Form, when click on element, go to link without hitting a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347080/dropdown-form-when-click-on-element-go-to-link-without-hitting-a-submit-button)

Comment: I don't need the form to be able to work without a submit button. I'm more asking for advice on how to organize my CGI pages in a way where once the submit button is pressed on one page it can navigate to the next page based on the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, for that I have personally used the jQuery .Ajax call. Based on the drop down and submit, a async call to the cgi is sent with a specific name value/pair, and based on that name value pair, the specific page is created on the server side code. You can do a redirect to the page you want to go to. The ajax call has an option to wait until the page is created or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **against** trying to use [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) for any new websites.

Instead I would recommend using one of the several frameworks that are now available.

- [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use Dancer;
  get '/hi' => sub {
      "Hello World!"
  };
  dance;
  ```
- [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env perl
  use Mojolicious::Lite;
  # /
  get '/' => 'index';
  # /*
  get '/:groovy' => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->render_text($self->param('groovy'), layout => 'funky');
  };
  app->start;


  __DATA__
  @@ index.html.ep
  % layout 'funky';
  Yea baby!


  @@ layouts/funky.html.ep
  <!doctype html><html>
      <head><title>Funky!</title></head>
      <body><%= content %></body>
  </html>
  ```
- [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)

  <sup><sub>( The simplest of which requires several files, but may be worth it for large websites )</sub></sup>