# Dropdown Form, when click on element, go to link without hitting a submit button

Tags: html, forms

I have a dropdown form, and when the user clicks on an element I want them to go to the url I have in the code without hitting a submit button. Here is the code I have so far

```
<select name="mydropdown" class="styled" onChange="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
<option value="http://www.cats.com">Select Your Compliance Center</option>
<option value="http://www.funcats.com">Fresh Milk</option>
<option value="http://cutecats.com">Old Cheese</option>
<option value="http://lolcats.com">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably put the code into the question (using the code formatting option) to try to make this page more self contained. eg if pastebin isn't working or that snippet gets deleted then this question becomes meaningless which is bad. Especially given its only 6 lines of code. :)

Comment: One observation for the link you provided in comments is that you have multiple elements with teh same id (eg selectmydropdown). Depending on what you might have script doing then this could potentially break things...

Comment: @Chris, if you look at the dropdown in question (http://screencast.com/t/HXx2cATbPMg), the dropdown in question does have a different id. I have updated the post to include the code now.

Comment: See http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html — especially the parts about why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @David, so just make an itemized list and make that the dropdown?

Comment: Better to just having it visible in the first place. http://message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks

Comment: well the dropdown is visible and seems to work in all browsers (note: in mobiles you would have to build a dropdown anyway), so at this point it's either stick with it or make an ul.

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
<select name="mydropdown" class="styled" onChange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">
        <option value="http://www.cats.com">Select Your Compliance Center</option>
        <option value="http://cutecats.com">Old Cheese</option>
        <option value="http://lolcats.com">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This seems to work on its own (see http://jsfiddle.net/hPdm3/). Can you clarify which part of that page should be exhibiting this forwarding behaviour?

Comment: weird, maybe the javascript i am using to display the background image on the form is hindering it (http://screencast.com/t/HXx2cATbPMg)?

Comment: Hey, please try this: onChange="document.location=this.value;"

Comment: HollerTrain: I suspect that it is other script. In particular you already have an onchange event firing related to the custom form elements code. One strange thing I noticed is that if I changed the inline onchange event to have a "alert('foo');" first (with no other code changes) then it fired the alert and then afterwards successfully did the redirect. I'm not posting an answer currently because although I think I know where its going wrong I'm not 100% sure of a ncie fix for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same as the other answer, but this one goes through a form.

```
<form name="linkForm" method="POST" action="" id="form">
  <select name="mydropdown" class="styled" onchange="document.getElementById('form').setAttribute('action', this.value); document.linkForm.submit(); ">
    <option value="http://www.cats.com">Select Your Compliance Center</option>
    <option value="http://www.funcats.com">Fresh Milk</option>
    <option value="http://cutecats.com">Old Cheese</option>
    <option value="http://lolcats.com">Hot Bread</option>
  </select>
</form>
```